# How to get the url from extracted information from a website

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

So basically I am stuck on the problem where I don't know how to the url from the extracted data from a website.

Here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

req = requests.get('https://api.randomtube.xyz/video.get?chan=2ch.hk&board=b&page=1')

soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, "html.parser")

print(soup.prettify())
```

I get a lot of information on output, but the only thing I need is the url, I hope someone can help me.

P.S:

It gives me this information:

```
{"response":{"items":[{"url":"https:\/\/2ch.hk\/b\/src\/262671212\/16440825183970.webm","type":"video\/webm","filesize":"20259","width":1280,"height":720,"name":"1521967932778.webm","board":"b","thread":"262671212"},{"url":"https:\/\/2ch.hk\/b\/src\/261549765\/16424501976450.webm","type":"video\/webm","filesize":"12055","width":1280,"height":720,"name":"1526793203110.webm","board":"b","thread":"261549765"}...
```

But i only need this part out of all the things
`https:\/\/2ch.hk\/b\/src\/261549765\/16424501976450.webm` (Not exactly this url, but just as an example)

Comment: What url? What's the markup/content look like? How is anyone going to be able to help you with the information you've provided so far? Please provide more details.

Comment: @h0r53 I'm sorry, I changed the information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The url produces json data. Beautifulsoup can't grab json data and to grab json data, you can follow the next example.

```
import requests
import json
        
data = requests.get('https://api.randomtube.xyz/video.get?chan=2ch.hk&board=b&page=1').json()
        
url= data['response']['items'][0]['url']
if url:
   url=url.replace('.webm','.mp4')
   print(url)
```

Output:

```
https://2ch.hk/b/src/263361969/16451225633240.mp4
```

Comment: By the way, @F.Hoque could you also help me please, if I wanted to get rid of the .webm, what would be the code just to have the .mp4?

Comment: thank you so much, just my last question is there a way to check if the link contains a video? Because in the extracted links, not all of them are valid. I would glad if you could help me with this. And also If I want to get only 1 link, but not all of them what should I change?

Comment: There is no way here to check the validity. You have to do that maually or to take help from another technology.Thanks

Comment: Also I don't think that you saw my edit, but if I was to get only 1 link, but not all of the links what should I change? And I wanted not to change the format, but to remove the link from the list

Comment: @CrazyChaos if you want to get 1link then you have to do list slicing like: url= data['response']['items'][0]['url']

Comment: Oh nvm, it works

Comment: I've updated again

Comment: Also I think you made it that whenever there is .webm, it changes the format to .mp4, but I want to remove the link from the list if the is a .webm, is this possible to make or no ? I might wrong, I'm sorry

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

```
url_array = []

for item in soup['response']['items']:
  url_array.append(item['url'])
```

I guess if the API returns JSON data then it should be better to just parse it directly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are telling BeautifulSoup to parse JSON data as HTML. You can get the URL you need more directly with the following code

```
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

req = requests.get('https://api.randomtube.xyz/video.get?chan=2ch.hk&board=b&page=1')

data = json.loads(req.content)
my_url = data['response']['items'][0]['url']
```