# How to get rid of .webm links in python request

Tags: python, python-requests

I have this code which gets the link of a video from a website that randomly generates a video in different formats (like .webm and mp4), although the link is not always valid, but I want python to check if the link contains the video (idk if it is possible) and to redo the process if the link on the output is in .webm format.

P.S: **Not to replace** the .webm to .mp4, but **to redo** the whole process if the video is .webm!

```
import json
import requests

data = requests.get('https://api.randomtube.xyz/video.get?chan=2ch.hk&board=b&page=1').json()
for item in data['response']['items']:
    url = data['response']['items'][0]['url']
    print(url)
```

The output I get:

`https://2ch.hk/b/src/261535136/16424379947461.webm`
(The **bad** output with the format I don't need)

`https://2ch.hk/b/src/263391417/16451696588520.mp4`
(The **good** output with the format I need)

Thank you!

Comment: Couple of questions: what's "the whole process"? Also, can you please fix the indentation of your code?

Comment: Why not just check that with `if url.endswith('.webm')`?

Comment: What do you mean by _"redo the process"_?

Comment: @aaossa the whole process is to get the link of a video from a website (the website itself gets a random video from the internet) also fixed the indenation.

Comment: @MendelG so if the link ends on .webm, it will request for a new video link from the website

Comment: Unless you control the server, you cannot guarantee the mp4 link exists for any given webm video, so making a new request wouldn't help

Comment: @OneCricketeer but the thing is the website contains a lot of videos and some of them are in different format, just like in .webm and .mp4, everytime you never know if it will be .mp4 or .webm

Comment: You could mention related posts, like your [previous question on the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71341533/how-to-get-the-url-from-extracted-information-from-a-website)

Comment: Is the list always going to contsin videos of the same format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issues to solve:

- [`endswith(part)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith) on a string returns `True` if the string ends with a given *part*, e.g. extension `.mp4`
- use the iteration variable `item` directly instead of always the first element of all items `data['response']['items'][0]`

```
for item in data['response']['items']:
     url = item['url']
     if url.endswith('.mp4'):
         print(url)
```

Prints not the 6 (`.webm`), but the 23 of the total 29 URLs. The ones that end with desired extension `.mp4`.

#### Refined

To get only the first `.mp4` I would wrap it into a function and return on the first found MP4 link.

```
def firstMp4(json):
     for item in json['items']:
         url = item['url']
         if url.endswith('.mp4'):
             return url
     return None  # default if no mp4 found


data = requests.get('https://api.randomtube.xyz/video.get?chan=2ch.hk&board=b&page=1').json()

mp4 = firstMp4(data['response'])
print(f"First mp4 or None: {mp4}")

if mp4 is None:
    print("No MP4 found.")
```

Comment: What if I was to need only 1 link out of all of them?

Comment: @CrazyChaos Which one? The first `.mp4`? Just edit your question and specify what you need exactly :)

Comment: yea, first one @hc_dev

Comment: Also do you by any chance if there is a way to check if the link contains a video? Since in my case not all the links the website gives are valid, when you open them sometimes it gives a 404 error. If you know could you please help

Answer (score 1):

You could create a flag to stop a while loop unless you find a "valid" (useful?) URL:

```
redo_process = True
while redo_process:
    data = requests.get('https://api.randomtube.xyz/video.get?chan=2ch.hk&board=b&page=1').json()
    for item in data["response"]["items"]:
        url = data["response"]["items"][0]["url"]
        if url.endswith(".webm"):
            # If we don't want this result, just break the loop and start again
            break
        # If this is what we want, just keep going and we'll stop the process at the end
        redo_process = False
        print(url)
```

Comment: If the first video is a `.mp4`, the next one is a `.webm`, and the next 10 are `.mp4` videos, this will print out a single URL for the first video. However, if the first 10 videos are `.mp4` videos, and the next one is a `.webm`, then it will print out 10 URLs for the `.mp4` videos.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this. This uses a [while loop](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#while) to keep us in a loop, requesting random videos from the API, and looping over the videos returned from the API, until we come across one that matches the desired condition: `not url.endswith('.mp4')`.

```
import json
import requests

url = ''
while not url.endswith('.mp4'):

    data = requests.get('https://api.randomtube.xyz/video.get?chan=2ch.hk&board=b&page=1').json()

    for item in data['response']['items']:
        url = item['url']
        if url.endswith('.mp4'):
            break
print(url)
```

I fixed a bug where `url = data['response']['items'][0]['url']` will always refer to the first URL from api.randomtube.xyz. Instead you want to use `url = item['url']` to refer to the URL from the current item of the loop.

To further improve things, we can put this into a function which feels nicer. Let me try to put into words why it feels nicer:

1. We have our re-usable `get_random_mp4_video` function which even if we only need to use it once, just having it separate helps us to easily understand understand what is going on on a surface level when reading through the code.
2. When we `return` out of the function we automatically stop going through both loops and this allows us to remove the check on the while loop. Now that we no longer have to check the URL in two different places, we prevents any problems where we might update one condition and forget about the other one.
3. This also makes the code a little bit easier to read. As we look through what is happening at each indentation, we at a glance catch that there an infinite loop, another loop, and the mp4 check, and that would lead us to quickly understand that we are performing an infinite loop until we get a `.mp4` file.

```
def get_random_mp4_video():

    while True:
        data = requests.get('https://api.randomtube.xyz/video.get?chan=2ch.hk&board=b&page=1').json()

        for item in data['response']['items']:
            url = item['url']
            if url.endswith('.mp4'):
                return url
```

Example usage that prints the first URL that does not give an error:

```
while True:
    url = get_random_mp4_video()
    resp = requests.get(url)
    # Check that we don't get a 404 or other error when visiting the URL
    if resp.ok:
        break
print(url)
```

The code could be further polished by bailing after a certain amount of tries to prevent an infinite loop if say `api.randomtube.xyz` is down or something else happens that gets us stuck in the loop, but I'll leave that to you to implement that additional protection. You would just need to add a basic counter and raise an error if the count gets too high.

### Bonus

**Returning multiple videos**

If you wanted to return multiple videos, without having to make multiple calls to `get_random_mp4_video` which would be inefficient due to waiting around for a lot of calls to `api.randomtube.xyz`, the following code is one way of doing that. I'm using two functions. The outer function is what you call, and you tell it how many videos you want. The inner `_get_vids` function gathers all of the mp4 videos from an `api.randomtube.xyz` request. The outer function will keep calling the inner function until it has enough videos to meet however many videos you asked for.

```
def get_random_mp4_videos(how_many):

    def _get_vids():
        ret = []
        data = requests.get('https://api.randomtube.xyz/video.get?chan=2ch.hk&board=b&page=1').json()

        for item in data['response']['items']:
            url = item['url']
            if url.endswith('.mp4'):
                ret.append(url)
        return ret

    vids = []
    while len(vids) < how_many:
        vids.extend(_get_vids())

    # we may have more videos than we need so return the first how_many videos
    return vids[:how_many]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just save all the links where they [`endswith()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith) *mp4*:

```
mp4_links = [link["url"] for link in data if link.get("url").endswith("mp4")]
print(mp4_links)
```

Comment: Although an elegant and clean solution, for someone not experienced with loops the advanced concept of _pythonic_ list-comprehension may be overwhelming.

Comment: @hc_dev Correct, since there are other answers, the OP can still choose from them